# Windows Small System Icon Height Incorrect

Tags: icons, windows-10, delphi-7

I'm running on Windows 10, but using Delphi 7 (yes, I know it's quite old).

I want to use the system icons in Windows and have gone about this by defining a `TImageList` called `SystemIcons` which I initialize as follows:

```
var
  fileInfo: TSHFileInfo;

begin
  SystemIcons.Handle := ShGetFileInfo('', 0, fileInfo, SizeOf(fileInfo),
    SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);

...
```

I have `SystemIcons` properties set statically as a `TImageList` component with width and height set to 16.

Elsewhere, I wish to retrieve an icon from this image list given a valid shell object's image index. Because these are "small system icons", I expect them to be 16x16. The result of calling `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON)` yields 16. Oddly, the dimensions depend upon whether I retrieve them as a bitmap or an icon.

```
...
var
  icon: TIcon;
  bm: TBitmap;

begin
  ...
  icon := TIcon.Create;
  SystemIcons.GetIcon(imgIndex, icon);

  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  SystemIcons.GetBitmap(imgIndex, bm);
```

The `imgIndex` is correct and the same in both cases. The image retrieved is the same in each case, as expected. The dimensions of the bitmap (`bm.Width` and `bm.Height`) are also as expected: 16x16. However, the dimensions of the icon (`icon.Width` and `icon.Height`) are not. They are 32x32.

When I paint the icon on a canvas it appears as 16x16. So it's only its `Height` and `Width` values that appear incorrect. Very odd.

Why are these different?

Comment: How many screens are attached to your computer. Is one of them high dpi?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan just one screen. I'm using a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The images are likely actually 32x32 to begin with.

Internally, `TImageList.GetIcon()` simply retrieves an `HICON` for the chosen image directly from the underlying Win32 ImageList API, using `ImageList_GetIcon()`, and assigns that to the `TIcon.Handle` property.

`TImageList.GetBitmap()`, on the other hand, is a bit different. It sizes the `TBitmap` to the dimensions of the `TImageList` (16x16), and then stretch draws the chosen image onto the `TBitmap.Canvas` using `TImageList.Draw()`, which in turn uses `ImageList_DrawEx()`.

Comment: Why then does `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON)` return 16? And the Icon, when I paint it on the screen as an icon, not as a bitmap, appears as 16x16? It's just the `Height` and `Width` properties that seem off. All other behaviors indicate it is 16x16.

Comment: @lurker: if you read the documentation, `SM_CYSMICON` is a "recommended" height, not an absolute. On the other hand, if the icon renders as 16x16, then it could just be a bug in the `TIcon` properties in D7. For instance, in D6, if the icon data has not been parsed in memory yet, `TIcon.Height` returns `SM_CYICON` instead of `SM_CYSMICON`

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. I glossed over the "recommended" adjective in the description. I tend to agree it could be a bug in the D7 handling of `TIcon`.

Comment: I don't believe that this is accurate. An image list does not hold icons. It's actually just a large rectangular bitmap. Well two bitmaps because there is a mask too. My expectation is that the image list has 32px images in it. There's probably some per monitor DPI going on.

Comment: I've factored out the TImageList from the equation and did a version of code that just retrieves the file icon individually by creating a `TIcon`, calling `SHGetFileInfo( pFilePath, 0, fileInfo,
                 SizeOf(fileInfo), SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SMALLICON );`, and then changing the handle of the TIcon to `fileInfo.hIcon`. This still shows a `TIcon` height property of 32 although it displays as 16.